# Creating a Facebook sign-in button with Slim and AwesomeFont

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, twitter-bootstrap, font-awesome, slim-lang

I came across this guide to creating a Facebook sign-in button for my Rails app using AwesomeFont:

http://tech.yeesiang.com/social-login-button-with-font-awesome-bootstrap/

It looks awesome, and *seems* simple to make.

My rails app uses Slim, so I converted the code to Slim:

```
.btn-group
  a.btn.btn-primary.disabled
    i.fa.fa-facebook style=("width:16px; height:20px") 
  a.btn.btn-primary href="" style="width:12em"  Sign in with Facebook
```

It looked *almost* right - figured out height: had to be set to 17px, and it lined up perfectly.

However I'm having trouble getting it to link to the right place. I'm using Omniauth, so it should link to user_omniauth_authorize_path(:facebook). The code I borrowed uses a href attribute. I'm not sure how to wrestle it to use rails paths instead.

How can this code be refactored to create a Facebook sign-in button that points to user_omniauth_authorize_path(:Facebook)?

Answer (score 0):

Read documentation of slim for ruby: http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/slim/frames

You can add [dynamic content tag:](http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/slim/file/README.md#Dynamic_content____and____)

```
.btn-group
  a.btn.btn-primary.disabled
    i.fa.fa-facebook style=("width:16px; height:20px") 
  = link_to "Sign in with Facebook", user_omniauth_authorize_path(:facebook),
            class: "btn btn-primary", style: "width: 12em"
```

OR

[interpolate href attribute](http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/slim/file/README.md#Quoted_attributes):

```
.btn-group
  a.btn.btn-primary.disabled
    i.fa.fa-facebook style=("width:16px; height:20px") 
  a.btn.btn-primary href="#{user_omniauth_authorize_path(:facebook)}" style="width:12em"  Sign in with Facebook
```

Comment: Thanks. Interpolation is what I ended up going with.